# Module 'cloud_firestore' not found

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am coding an app that is made on Flutter. I use Firebase Firestore as a database. I added cloud_firestore as a dependency in pubspec.yaml. When I build the apk for android it works perfectly fine, but in Xcode when I'm trying to build the app for iOS I have an error ( attached image ) 'Module cloud_firestore' not found, all the other dependencies are working. I've tried everything: pod install, pod update, remove Podfile, remove Podfile.lock, I even created a blank app and added cloud_firestore as dependency and it still happens.

Comment: Can you add your podfile here?

Answer (score 0):

- inxcode, clean build folder.
- In terminal, `flutter clean`
- `flutter pub get` in terminal.

Don't touch the pods, build your file.

Comment: Hello Huthaifa, thanks for answering. I tried what you suggested and other things but I couldn't solve it. Do you have any other suggestions to fix it? Thanks